# ¿Cómo imprimir el valor de un input tipo time al hacer click a un checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html

No encuentro como imprimir el valor tipo time que seleccioné, en todos los td que se generan con la lista, cuando le doy a seleccionar, se seleccionan todo los checkbox como quiero pero sólo en el primer input se me imprime la fecha que seleccioné, la función que uso es:

```
function toggle(source) {
  var fecha = document.getElementById("desde_fijo").value;
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("myCheck");

  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    console.log(fecha);
    if (("checked", true)) {
      document.getElementById(
        "input_control_hora_inicio"
      ).value = document.getElementById("desde_fijo").value;
    }
  }
}
```

Y los input son los siguientes primero el que selecciono la hora y luego donde requiero se imprima:

```
<th class="text-center th_yura_green" style="border-color: white; border-radius:  18px 0 0 0">
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" name="myCheck" onchange="toggle(this)" />
</th>
<th class="text-center th_yura_green" style="border-color: white;">Inicio
  <input class="text-center" type="time" style="width:100%;  color:#00b388" id="desde_fijo" name="desde_fijo">
</th>
<td class="text-center" style="border-color: #9d9d9d">
  <input class="text-center" type="time" style="width:100%" id="input_control_hora_inicio" name="input_control_hora_inicio">
</td>
```

imagen:
[image: formulario]

Comment: Todos las filas (`<tr>`) tienen los mismos identificadores en `input type="checkbox"` y  `input class="text-center"`?

Comment: Si @milmal todas las filas tienen los mismos identificadores!

Answer (score 0):

Se supone que las identificaciones son únicas. Entonces se espera que solo cambie la primera instancia con la identificación.

Si te he entendido bien, establecería un `onChange` evento en `<input type="time">`. Luego podrá verificar cuántas casillas de verificación desea y agregar un tiempo que se establecerá en todas las entradas con el nombre de clase de `inicio`.

```js
const checkbox = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");
const inicio = document.getElementsByClassName("inicio");

function agregarTiempo(source) {
  if (source.value) {
    Object.keys(inicio).forEach((i) => {
      if (checkbox[i].checked) {
        inicio[i].value = source.value;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center th_yura_green" style="border-color: white; border-radius: 18px 0 0 0;">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="0" />
    </th>
    <th class="text-center th_yura_green" style="border-color: white;">
      Inicio
      <input class="inicio text-center" type="time" style="width: 100%; color: #00b388;" name="desde_fijo" onchange="agregarTiempo(this)" />
    </th>
    <td class="text-center" style="border-color: #9d9d9d;">
      <input class="text-center" type="time" style="width: 100%;" name="input_control_hora_inicio" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center th_yura_green" style="border-color: white; border-radius: 18px 0 0 0;">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="1" />
    </th>
    <th class="text-center th_yura_green" style="border-color: white;">
      Inicio
      <input class="inicio text-center" type="time" style="width: 100%; color: #00b388;" name="desde_fijo" onchange="agregarTiempo(this)" />
    </th>
    <td class="text-center" style="border-color: #9d9d9d;">
      <input class="text-center" type="time" style="width: 100%;" name="input_control_hora_inicio" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center th_yura_green" style="border-color: white; border-radius: 18px 0 0 0;">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="2" />
    </th>
    <th class="text-center th_yura_green" style="border-color: white;">
      Inicio
      <input class="inicio text-center" type="time" style="width: 100%; color: #00b388;" name="desde_fijo" onchange="agregarTiempo(this)" />
    </th>
    <td class="text-center" style="border-color: #9d9d9d;">
      <input class="text-center" type="time" style="width: 100%;" name="input_control_hora_inicio" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```